# ¿Cuándo y cómo se originó la expresión "meter la pata"?

Tags: expresiones, historia

Según el diccionario:

> [**meter** alguien **la pata**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S71hGRM#8arje3S)
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Hacer o decir algo inoportuno o equivocado.

¿Por qué *pata*, y no *pie* o *pierna*? Esta expresión, según el blog de Alfred López *Ya está el listo que todo lo sabe*, tiene [dos posibles orígenes](https://blogs.20minutos.es/yaestaellistoquetodolosabe/cual-es-el-origen-de-la-expresion-meter-la-pata/):

- Uno literal, en el que la expresión se refiere a cuando un animal era capturado en una trampa metiendo la pata en ella.
- Otro como corrupción de la expresión *mentar a pateta*, dado que [*pateta*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=S950eEB) se usa para referirse al diablo.

¿Existen otras explicaciones para el origen de la expresión? ¿Se puede rastrear en textos el origen de la misma? ¿Cuándo comenzó a usarse en textos escritos?

Yo lo que he encontrado de momento es un primer caso no literal de la expresión en el CORDE hacia 1872 (hay otros pero son literales, tipo "el animal metió la pata en el hoyo" o así):

> *Ella sin embargo se empeñaba en afinarse y a lo mejor por querer decir las cosas bien, solía cometer esas garrafales faltas de estilo que el vulgo llama grosera pero gráficamente meter la pata.*
>
> Benito Pérez Galdós, "Rosalía", c1872 (España).

De la palabra "pateta" encuentro algunos casos, pero ninguno de "mentar a pateta".

Comment: También lo he escuchado: "meter las de caminar"

Answer (score 7):

Viene de cuando antiguamente no había cuarto de baño en las casas y lo normal era dormir con un orinal junto a la cama, en el cual durante la noche se hacían las aguas tanto [menores](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BKpQj3#BoDnnvU) como [mayores](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BKpQj3#BoDgmFr) (de aquí viene también, por cierto, la expresión "[¡Agua va!](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1BKpQj3#BobcjJG)").

A veces pasaba que te levantabas de la cama y, si no tenías cuidado, **metías *literalmente* la pata** (o lo que es lo mismo: el pie<sup>1</sup>) **en el orinal**. Con todas sus asquerosas consecuencias. De ahí el que Galdós lo defina como expresión "grosera pero gráfica".

<sub><sup>1</sup> Consultando el [NTTLE](http://buscon.rae.es/ntlle/SrvltGUILoginNtlle) se puede ver que "pata" tiene la acepción de "pie" durante al menos los siglos XV (Nebrija: "planta del pie"), XVI (Nebrija y Percival, mismo significado), XVII (Covarrubias: "comúnmente pie ancho y extendido"), y XVIII y principios del XIX (diccionarios de la Academia: "pie y pierna de los animales. Del hombre se dice menos cultamente").</sub>

NOTA: Tras un rato buscando no he podido encontrar ninguna fuente que me apoye. Si lo leí en un libro, o una revista en papel, o cualquier otro formato físico similar, va a ser complicado encontrarlo :( pero ése es el origen que conozco.